# python: increase performance of finding the best timeshift for a correlation between each X column and y

Tags: python, performance, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a dataframe X with several columns and a dataframe y with only one column (series). The rows in X represent timesteps and I want to find the interval I need to shift each column of X to obtain the highest correlation with y. I wrote a function that loops over all columns and then loops over all timesteps and correlates the X column with y. If the R² is better than before I store the timestep. However, with over 300 columns this routine is really taking some time and I need to increase the performance. Is there a nice way to simplify this code?
(In the example I used the iris data set which is of course not a timeseries...)

```
from sklearn import datasets
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from copy import deepcopy

def get_best_shift(dfX, dfy, ti=60, maxt=1440):
    """
    determines the best correlation for the last maxt minutes based on a  
    timestep of ti minutes. Creates a dataframe with the shifted variables based on the 
    best match (strongest correlation). 
    """
    df_out = deepcopy(dfX)
    for xcol in dfX:
        bestshift = 0
        Rmax = 0
        for ishift in range(0, int(maxt / ti)):
            xvals = dfX[xcol].iloc[0:(dfX.shape[0] - ishift)].values
            yvals = np.array([val[0] for val in dfy.iloc[ishift:dfy.shape[0]].values])
            selector = np.array([str(val)!="nan" for val in (xvals*yvals)],dtype=bool)
            xvals = xvals[selector]
            yvals = yvals[selector]
            R = np.corrcoef(xvals,yvals)[0][1]
            # plt.figure()
            # plt.plot(xvals,yvals,'k.')
            # plt.show()
            if R ** 2 > Rmax:
                Rmax = R ** 2
                # print(Rmax)
                bestshift = ishift
        df_out[xcol] = list(np.zeros(bestshift)) + list(dfX[xcol].iloc[0:dfX.shape[0] - bestshift].values)
        df_out = df_out.rename(columns={xcol: ''.join([str(xcol), '_t-', str(bestshift)])})

    return df_out

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = pd.DataFrame(iris.data)
y = pd.DataFrame(iris.target)

df = get_best_shift(X,y)
```

Comment: @jpp: is added now

Comment: I believe there’s no asymptotically faster algorithm for multiple cross-correlations, so you’re left with reducing copying and so forth.